# How to filter the Json value from API using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

I'm working on Angularjs. I'm facing difficulty in filter the data which comes from the API. The method i'm using for the API is post method. This API is been used for the search critetia for the Application. When the particular data is selected in the dropdown list and click on the search button the API triggers and shows the data in the table. But i'm getting an empty array.

Let me share you my controller page

```
$scope.generate = function() {
    $scope.searchResults = false
    if ($scope.query.selectedProduct || $scope.query.selectedBucket || $scope.query.selectedCity) {
      $scope.query.selectedBucket = ($scope.query.selectedBucket == "") ? null : $scope.query.selectedBucket
      $scope.query.selectedProduct = ($scope.query.selectedProduct == "") ? null : $scope.query.selectedProduct
      $scope.query.selectedCity = ($scope.query.selectedCity == "") ? null : $scope.query.selectedCity
       $scope.showLoader = true
      reportService.search($scope.query).success(function(data){
          $scope.query = data

        $scope.query = {
           "productGroup": $scope.query.selectedProduct,

            "currentBucket": $scope.query.selectedBucket,
            "branch":     $scope.query.selectedCity
        }

            console.log($scope.query.selectedBucket);
            $scope.showLoader = false
            setTimeout(function () {
                    //window.scroll(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');
            }, 200);
      $scope.results = data
      if($scope.results){
               console.log(data);
        $scope.searchResults = true
         _.forEach(data, function (obj) {
                     console.log("hi");
                  obj.isChecked = false;
                });
        $scope.view_data = $scope.results.slice($scope.skip, $scope.items + $scope.skip);
              $scope.totalItems = $scope.results.length;
              console.log(data.selectedBucket);

      }else{
        $scope.searchResults = false
        notificationFactory.warning('No results Found')
                $scope.showLoader = false
      }

      }).error(function(data) {
        notificationFactory.warning('Error Searching Reports')
        console.log(data);
      })
    } else {
      //console.log('Please enter atleast one search Criteria')
      notificationFactory.warning('Please enter atleast one search Criteria')
    }
  }
```

And here is my Html page

```
<!--Breadcrumb starts here-->
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#/account/home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="active">Reports</li>
  <li class="active">Collection Reports</li>
</ol>
<!--allocation starts here-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <form class="form-holder" role="search" ng-submit="generate()">


        <h3>Collection Reports</h3>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid loan_deatils">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12">




                <br>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Product Group:<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" name="productGroup" ng-model="query.selectedProduct" ng-options="product.productGroup for product in products">

                    <option value="">Select Role</option>
                  </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Product : </label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" name="productCode" ng-model="query.selectedProduct" ng-options="product.productCode for product in products">

                    <option value="">Select Role</option>
                  </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Current Bucket :<i class="mandate">*</i></label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" ng-model="query.selectedBucket" name="currentBucket" ng-options="b.bucket for b in buckets">
                    <option value="">Select Role</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="memberForm.role.$error.required && memberForm.role.$dirty">Select Role</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>State: </label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="newMember.address.state" ng-options="state for state in states" ng-change="getCities()">
                    <option value="">-- Select State --</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="memberForm.state.$error.required && memberForm.state.$dirty">Select State</span>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='search_controls.selected_agency' 
                                                typeahead="agency.firstName for agency in agency_list | filter:$viewValue"
                                                typeahead-editable="isEditable"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>City: </label>
                  <select id="Select" class="form-control" ng-model="newMember.address.city" name="city" ng-options="city for city in cityList">
                    <option value="">-- Select City --</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="error" ng-show="memberForm.city.$error.required && memberForm.city.$dirty">Select City</span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
                  <select class="form-control input-md" name='branch' ng-model="query.selectedCity" ng-options="branch as branch.branchName for branch in baseBranches">
                    <option value="" selected>-- Select Branch --</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Generate Report</button><img src="{{indicator}}" height="16px" width="16px" ng-show='showLoader' />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12" id="chart-container"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid" ng-show='searchResults'>
              <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <!--search agent starts here-->
                    <div class="search-result">
                      <h3>Search Result</h3>
                      <div class="inside_table receipt-book">
                        <div class="table-responsive" id="flip-scroll">
                          <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>

                              <tr name="currentBucket">
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">SZ_ACCOUNT_ID</th>
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">SZ_BRANCH_NAME</th>
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">SZ_LOAN_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID </th>
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">Bucket MOB</th>
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">F_OUTSTANDING_PRINCIPAL</th>
                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order">F_NEXT_EMI_AMOUNT</th>

                                <th ng-click='sortColumn()' reverse="reverse" th-sort by="order"> SZ_CRO_ID</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr ng-repeat="item in view_data | orderBy:order:reverse">
                                <td><span>{{item.productCode}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.sZ_BRANCH_NAME}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.sZ_LOAN_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.bucketMOB}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.f_outstandinG_PRINCIPAL}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.f_nexT_EMI_AMOUNT}}</span></td>
                                <td><span>{{item.sZ_CRO_ID}}</span></td>
                              </tr>

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--/inside table-->
                      <!--pagination starts here-->
                      <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="dataTables_info1">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                              <div>Showing
                                <select ng-model='itemsPerView' class="form-control" ng-options='c for c in [2,5,10,15,20,30,40,50]' ng-change='changeItemsPerPage()'>
                                </select> Collection Reports</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 ">
                              <pagination boundary-links="true" ng-change="pageChanged()" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;" num-pages="numPages" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" max-size="10"
                              class="pull-right">
                              </pagination>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--pagination ends here-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--/row ends -->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the API shows the value for the following data which i checked in  postman.

```
{
  "productGroup": "",
  "product": "",
  "currentBucket": 2,
  "branch": ""
}
```

Please help me out of this on  how to  display the data in  the table After selecting the search criteria because i'm a new bee to developing side.

Comment: Have you checked your console to be sure there are no errors? You could make this easier to get a response by isolating relevant parts of the code in your question.

Comment: @ kubuntu can i  know what are relevant parts of the code in my question you are asking  about ?